# How do I enable undo in eclipse ant editor?

Tags: eclipse, ant, release-management, build-management

Undo is not working for me in ant editor in eclipse.
When I press Ctrl-Z nothing happens.

Is it possible to enable undo somehow or is this a bug?

I am using Eclipse 3.4.2 (Ganymede) on Windows XP Professional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes undo should be working perfectly in an ant editor.
For `Ctrl-Z` to not workcould mean:

- the shortcut has been assigned to another action (`Windows > Preferences > General > Keys`)
- the undo buffer size is somehow at '0' (`Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editor`)
- a plugin somehow 'steals' the key event for itself

Try a fresh install, and check also with a latest Galileo (3.5RC2) install to see if the problem persist.

---

Note: [zvikico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico) mentions the existence of a known bug with ant editor in 3.4.2

After a [quick search](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&short_desc=&classification=Eclipse&component=Ant&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=undo&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=), the following bugs might explain your situation:

- [267780](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=267780) [ant editor] delete line cannot be undone after cursor has been moved
- [247434](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=247434) Failed to undo removal of line in Ant editor, only with **'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers'**, with Eclipse Classic you don't get this behavior

and finally:

- [239115](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239115) Undo functionality does not work anymore in the ant editor, mainly because a WTP issue, only solved in 3.5

Comment: Don't bother checking the preferences. It is a known bug in 3.4.2. It is solved in 3.5.

Comment: @zivkico: good point. I suppose you are referring to 239115, meaning undo does not work with ant editor only if you have WTP added to your eclipse3.4. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, the point about WTP made things really clear.
It also explains why in some of my eclipse 3.4.2 installs the undo feature works.

Answer (score 2):

I see this post is very old, but I am adding a response for the people who find this through the search engines.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> stopped working in eclipse for me when I made a small change in one part of my code which in turn triggered an unexpected infinite loop in a different part of my code.

- I used the windows task manager to kill the application that I had been testing when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> had stopped working, and then I used `system.out.println()` to identify the part of the code where the infinite loop was being triggered.
- I then disabled that section of code, which in turn caused <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and everything else to start working again.
- I was able to finish debugging from there.

Comment: Interesting feedback, a practical example in addition to my original answer from almost 4 years ago. +1

Answer (score 2):

If the CTRL-Z (undo) does not work anymore, you might try that. It worked for me:
go to Preferences -> General -> Keys and click on apply button or restore defaults button