# Eclipse Undo/Redo Binding Key Shortcuts Not Working

Tags: eclipse, binding, shortcut, undo, redo

I am currently working with Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0) on a Mac. When I go to Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys the Undo and Redo shortcut bindings are set to Command Z and Command Shift Z, respectively. However, when I try to undo / redo code that I am writing in PyDev perspective, the shortcuts do not work. Even the Undo/Redo in the Edit field are greyed out and cannot be manually done. Any idea why this is happening and how it can be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be duplicated or, at least, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927851/undo-shortcut-not-working-in-eclipse) you can find a similar issue.

Comment: I have checked that thread and similar threads and it has not helped my problem.

Comment: Have you also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913059/how-do-i-enable-undo-in-eclipse-ant-editor)? It explains some possible sources for this error.